# split an array into two based on a index in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I have an array with a list of objects. I want to split this array at one particular index, say 4 (this in real is a variable). I want to store the second part of the split array into another array. Might be simple, but I am unable to think of a nice way to do this.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), as such:

```js
var ar = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
    
var p1 = ar.slice(0,4);
console.log({p1});

var p2 = ar.slice(4);
console.log({p2});
```

Comment: what happens with arrays that are too short [1,2.3].slice(4) ?

Comment: @Xanlantos it will return an array that is identical to the original.

Comment: @KyleSoeltz I believe that is inaccurate and it actually returns an empty array. I've just tested this. This behavior seems preferable to me.

Comment: @ZainSyed Ah yes you are correct. I misread the question and was thinking [1,2,3].slice(0,4) which will return an identical array. [1,2,3].slice(4) will return an empty array.

Comment: I believe in most cases, you should use splice instead because slice does not reset the index.

Answer (score 28):

You can use [`Array@splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to chop all elements after a specified index off the end of the array and return them:

```
x = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"];
y = x.splice(3);
console.log(x); // ["a", "b", "c"]
console.log(y); // ["d", "e", "f", "g"]
```

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend to use slice() like below

`ar.slice(startIndex,length);`
or
`ar.slice(startIndex);`

```js
var ar = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g"];

var p1 = ar.slice(0,3);
var p2 = ar.slice(3);

console.log(p1);
console.log(p2);
```

Answer (score 5):

use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```
var bigOne = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6];
var splittedOne = bigOne.slice(3 /*your Index*/);
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
const splitAt = (i, arr) => {
  const clonedArray = [...arr];
  return [clonedArray.splice(0, i), clonedArray];
}

const [left, right] = splitAt(1, [1,2,3,4])

console.log(left) // [1]
console.log(right) // [2,3,4]


const [left1, right1] = splitAt(-1, [1,2,3,4])

console.log(left1) // []
console.log(right1) // [1,2,3,4]


const [left2, right2] = splitAt(5, [1,2,3,4])

console.log(left1) // [1,2,3,4]
console.log(right1) // []
```

Some benefits compared to other solutions:

1. You can get the result with a one liner
2. When split index is underflow or overflow, the result is still correct. `slice` will not behave correctly.
3. It does not mutate the original array. Some `splice` based solutions did.
4. There is only 1 `splice` operation, rather than 2 `slice` operations. But you need to benchmark to see if there is actual performance difference.

Comment: I find this answer way cooler, clone the array and then perfom the operations. Great work.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use underscore/lodash wrapper:

```
var ar = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var p1 = _.first(ar, 4);
var p2 = _.rest(ar, 4);
```

Comment: `_.first` is an alias for `_.head`, which does not take a second argument. https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#first

Answer (score 0):

Simple one function from lodash:

`const mainArr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
const [arr1, arr2] = _.chunk(mainArr, _.round(mainArr.length / 2));`

Answer (score 0):

```js
const splitArrayByIndex = (arr, index) => {
  if (index > 0 && index < arr.length) {
    return [arr.slice(0, index), arr.slice(-1 * (arr.length - index))]
  }
}

const input = ['a', 'x', 'c', 'r']
const output = splitArrayByIndex(input, 2)

console.log({ input, output })
```