# Split Javascript array elements into chunks at designated indexes

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I have an array like so

```
const arr = [3,6,9,12,18,21,24,27,33,36];
```

I want the array **arr** split into chunks at 12, 21 and 33. That is at the index 3, 5, and 8. I want to produce another array **chunks** looking like this..

```
const chunks = [[3,6,9,12],[18,21],[24,27,33],[36]];
```

The solutions I have seen here basically split arrays into 'n' chunks. Basically I want to split at arrays at several (specified) indexes.

I do not mind an underscore.js/lodash solution. Thanks

Comment: How is this question a duplicate of [split an array into two based on a index in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872630/split-an-array-into-two-based-on-a-index-in-javascript) ? The answers there address spliting  an array into 2 albeit by index, mine into several parts.

Comment: It's not exact duplicate, but there is no way to split it in one operation as for example can be done for strings. Each part of the array has to be extracted separately in a loop.

Answer (score 6):

You could use [`reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight) and decide which elements to split at. Since you’re providing the *last* values of a sub-array rather than the *first* ones, going from right to left is actually a bit easier, hence I use a `reduceRight` rather than a [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

### Split by value

```js
const arr = [3, 6, 9, 12, 18, 21, 24, 27, 33, 36],
  splitValues = [12, 21, 33],
  chunks = arr.reduceRight((result, value) => {
    result[0] = result[0] || [];

    if (splitValues.includes(value)) {
      result.unshift([value]);
    } else {
      result[0].unshift(value);
    }

    return result;
  }, []);

console.log(chunks);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

### Split by index

```js
const arr = [3, 6, 9, 12, 18, 21, 24, 27, 33, 36],
  splitIndexes = [3, 5, 8],
  chunks = arr.reduceRight((result, value, index) => {
    result[0] = result[0] || [];

    if (splitIndexes.includes(index)) {
      result.unshift([value]);
    } else {
      result[0].unshift(value);
    }

    return result;
  }, []);

console.log(chunks);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
const arr = [3,6,9,12,18,21,24,27,33,36];

// Important: this array gets mutated. Make a copy if that's not okay.
const inds = [3,5,8];

const chunked = arr.reduce((p, c, i) => { if (i-1 === inds[0]) { inds.shift(); p.push([]); } p[p.length-1].push(c); return p; }, [[]]);

console.log(chunked)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative way of doing it that I think is a bit clearer.

```
function chunkIt(arr, indexes) {
    const ret = [];
    let last = 0;

    indexes.forEach(i => {
        ret.push(arr.slice(last, i + 1));
        last = i + 1;
    });
    if (last < arr.length) {
        ret.push(arr.slice(last));
    }
    return ret;
}

console.log(chunkIt([3,6,9,12,18,21,24,27,33,36], [3,5,8]));
```

Answer (score 2):

A bit "simplified" version with the reversed indexes, but `splice` modifies the source array:

```js
arr = [3, 6, 9, 12, 18, 21, 24, 27, 33, 36]

chunks = [9, 6, 4, 0].map(i => arr.splice(i)).reverse()

console.log(JSON.stringify(chunks))
```

or `slice` can be used instead to preserve the source array:

```js
arr = [3, 6, 9, 12, 18, 21, 24, 27, 33, 36], indexes = [0, 4, 6, 9]

chunks = indexes.map((e, i) => arr.slice(e, indexes[i + 1]))

console.log(JSON.stringify(chunks))
```