# Split list from textarea into chunks and add extra text using javascript

Tags: javascript, split

I have a list like this: `125,248,11,486,3554,89,55`

I need to have 2 textarea, in the first one i need to put the above list and after i click a button then in the second textarea i will get a list like this:

```
<!--startline-->[new text="table" ids="125,248,11"]
<!--startline-->[new text="table" files="2" ids="486,3554,89,55"]
```

So these are the rules:

- i need chunk size of 3 elements
- i need to add custom text before and after the chunk: `<!--startline-->[new text="table" ids="` + `chunk` + `"]`
- if the last chunk has 2 or 1 element, then i need to merge it with
  the previous one and the generated text for that chunk will be:
  `<!--startline-->[new text="table" files="2" ids="` + `chunk` + `"]`
- every custom text and chunk will be on a new line, like in the above example

I found something that could help, using `.slice` or `.splice` but the problem is that i need to add custom text and not making an array like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47061736/1773862

So, any ideas? :)

----------- **Solution**:

```js
const myList = document.getElementById('mylist');
const myNewList = document.getElementById('mynewlist');
const chunkSize = 3;
checkpoint = 0;
document.getElementById('generate').addEventListener('click', () => {
  let chunks = myList.value.trim().split(',').reduce((all, one, i) => {
    const ch = Math.floor(i / chunkSize);
     all[ch] = [].concat((all[ch] || []), one);
     checkpoint++;
     return all
  }, []);
  let lastChunk = [...chunks[chunks.length-1]]; 
  const lastone = chunks.length-2;
  //alert(lastone);
  if (lastChunk.length < chunkSize) {
    chunks = chunks.slice(0, -1);
    chunks[chunks.length - 1] = chunks[chunks.length - 1].concat(lastChunk);
    checkpoint = 1;
  }
  myNewList.value = chunks.map((chunk,i) => `<!--startline-->[new text="table" ids="${chunk.join(',')}"]`).join('\n');
  
   var content = myNewList.value;
   var lastLine = content.substr(content.lastIndexOf("\n")+1);
  var countnow = (lastLine.match(/,/g)||[]).length;
  if (countnow > 2) {  
  var elem = document.getElementById('mynewlist');
 var val  = elem.value.split(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/g).filter(function(n){return n.trim()});
 val.pop();
 elem.value = val.join('\r\n');
 lastLine = lastLine.replace("\"table\" ", "\"table\" \"files=\"2\" ");
 elem.value += "\n" + lastLine;
 }
  
});
```

```html
<textarea id="mylist">30318,30319,30320,30321,30322,30323,30324,30325,30326,30327,30328,30329,30330,30331,30332,30333,30334,30335,30336,30337,30338,30339,30340,30341,30342,30343,30344,30345,30346,30347,30348,30349,30350,30351,30352,30353,30354,30355,30356,30357,30358,30359,30360,30361,30362,30363,30364,30365,123,999</textarea>
<br><br>
<button id="generate">Generate new list</button>
<br><br>
<textarea id="mynewlist" style="width: 538px; height: 294px;"></textarea>
```

Thanks to @mplungjan for the first part of the solution!

Comment: @mplungjan, well i guess you did not see that i tried to find a solution, but hey, thanks!

Comment: @mplungjan i am not here to impress you, it's not a contest. I just asked for some help, not to do my work ;) so thanks a bunch. Have a nice day!

Comment: Well I did it anyway because I found it interesting and it is xmas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use split
2. Use a chunker - I found one at  [Split array into chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks)
3. You can use template literals to generate the strings

This one ONLY adds the files attribute on the last and ONLY if it has more than the chunksize

```js
const chunker = (list, size) => list.value.trim().split(',').reduce((acc, cur, i) => { const ch = Math.floor(i / size); acc[ch] = [].concat((acc[ch] || []), cur); return acc }, []);

const myList = document.getElementById('mylist');
const myNewList = document.getElementById('mynewlist');
const chunkSize = 3;
document.getElementById('generate').addEventListener('click', () => {
  let chunks = chunker(myList, chunkSize),
    lastChunk = [...chunks[chunks.length - 1]], 
    partial = lastChunk.length < chunkSize,
    max = chunks.length-2; // max is only used if partial
  if (partial) {
    chunks = chunks.slice(0, -1); // chop the last off
    chunks[chunks.length - 1] = chunks[chunks.length - 1].concat(lastChunk); // concat to new last chunk
  }
  myNewList.value = chunks.map((chunk, i) => `<!--startline-->[new text="table"${partial && i===max ? ' files="2"' : '' } ids="${chunk.join(',')}"]`).join('\n')

});
```

```css
#mynewlist {
  width: 700px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="mylist">30318,30319,30320,30321,30322,30323,30324,30325,30326,30327,30328,30329,30330,30331,30332,30333,30334,30335,30336,30337,30338,30339,30340,30341,30342,30343,30344,30345,30346,30347,30348,30349,30350,30351,30352,30353,30354,30355,30356,30357,30358,30359,30360,30361,30362,30363,30364,30365,123,999</textarea>
<br><br>
<button id="generate">Generate new list</button>
<br><br>
<textarea id="mynewlist"></textarea>
```

Comment: This works, but has a little bug: the  'files="2"' part needs to be only if the the last chunk has 2 or 1 element and only on the final chunk. Thank you for the help. I will try to solve the bug, i am used to use "while" in cases like this but i am not familiar with .map. I will search for more details about .map and see how it works. Thank you again!

Comment: The code is doing exactly what you asked tho. The last chunk has only 1 element in this example and you said that if that was the case, then it should merge with the previous one and that last chunk should have the `files=2` custom text

Comment: Here it is the code but with a bigger list: https://jsfiddle.net/62pfmt0k/ and this is some of the code, but working as i said in description - https://jsfiddle.net/qha9y2bx/ . @ChrisG, do you see the difference? mplungjan, thanks again!

Comment: @Crys See updated. I only add the files attr on the last now

Comment: @ChrisG I added the files attr to every line. I fixed that now

Comment: yeah I saw the difference on a larger list